# How to send one command to multiple PC's over LAN (linux)

Tags: ssh, debian, lan

O/S: Debian

Hi,

I've got multiple computers in a LAN network that I monitor remotely, they're all running the same hardware and software. To monitor them I simply ssh in to one computer and then ssh off that on to the others.

I was wondering if it was possible to send a command to the computers through ssh, that was then broadcast to the computers in the LAN (within a certain ip-range!)? e.g. For all the computers I want the command 'ls -l' to be run, from the ip range 10.1.1.10 - 10.1.1.18.

Or could I have them, e.g., to all run a bash script from one command? Is this possible or do I need some 3rd party program to implement this?

Thanks.

Comment: I suppose you could write a script and this way execute the commands and even avoid using password by using a private key to authenticate to these servers. Also try googling something called Parallel SSH (PSSH)

Comment: http://packages.debian.org/wheezy/mussh http://packages.debian.org/wheezy/clusterssh

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that [PSSH](http://www.netfort.gr.jp/~dancer/software/dsh.html.en) is the tool you are looking for. See [Execute commands simultaneously on multiple servers Using PSSH/Cluster SSH/Multixterm](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/execute-commands-simultaneously-on-multiple-servers-using-psshcluster-sshmultixterm.html).

An alternative is [DSH](http://www.netfort.gr.jp/~dancer/software/dsh.html.en). See [Running Remote Commands on Multiple Servers with SSH and Dsh](http://www.unixlore.net/articles/running-remote-commands-multiple-servers-ssh-dsh.html).

You may also take a look at [Puppet](http://puppetlabs.com/).

Answer (score 0):

First point would be you can have multiple terminals open to multiple SSH connections at once, but I assume you want a simple method of sending a single message to all machines at once.

There are a couple admin terminals which might help you here. I believe ClusterSSH (available through SourceForge) will do the job. You will have to forgive me, I have not personally tried this application, but have been told by others it allows for command echo across multiple systems. I assume this might be something you want. A brief look at the application can be found at [linux.com](http://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/413853-managing-multiple-linux-servers-with-clusterssh)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes I've been opening up multiple terminal sessions.

I will try ClusterSSH, thanks for your reply.