# Type in multiple terminals

Tags: ssh, terminal, console

I am looking for a solution for Windows to be able to type the same commands in multiple terminals (SSH) at the same time. I am using ConEmu with Git bash, but any solution for Windows is of interest.

Comment: See also http://superuser.com/questions/707517 and http://superuser.com/questions/725402

Comment: Ah, unfortunately this is not Windows as you requested, but still, take a look at http://serverfault.com/a/65656

Comment: @slhck those answers don't give the solution for Windows.

Comment: Any of these run under Cygwin. It seems there are quite a lot of parallel SSH tools out there anyway.